# how to string a jmxclient output?

Tags: string, jmx

i use cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar to get JMX info:

```
[root@TestProduction zabbix]#java -jar /etc/zabbix/cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - 127.0.0.1:9500 $(java -jar cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - 127.0.0.1:9500 |grep "com.mchange.v2.c3p0" |sed -n 1p) minPoolSize 
04/18/2017 10:46:47 +0800 org.archive.jmx.Client minPoolSize: 50
[root@TestProduction zabbix]#java -jar /etc/zabbix/cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - 127.0.0.1:9500 $(java -jar cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - 127.0.0.1:9500 |grep "com.mchange.v2.c3p0" |sed -n 1p) minPoolSize |awk '{print $6}'
04/18/2017 10:47:21 +0800 org.archive.jmx.Client minPoolSize: 50
[root@TestProduction zabbix]#echo "04/18/2017 10:47:21 +0800 org.archive.jmx.Client minPoolSize: 50" |awk '{print $6}'
50
[root@TestProduction zabbix]#java -jar /etc/zabbix/cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - 127.0.0.1:9500 $(java -jar cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - 127.0.0.1:9500 |grep "com.mchange.v2.c3p0" |sed -n 1p) minPoolSize |printf %s |awk '{print $6}'
04/18/2017 10:48:00 +0800 org.archive.jmx.Client minPoolSize: 50
```

how can i string the "04/18/2017 10:47:21 +0800 org.archive.jmx.Client minPoolSize: 50" to format as "50"?
i doubt the output may not a string?
any1 know it?  thx. :)

Answer (score 0):

[root@TestProduction zabbix]#java -jar /etc/zabbix/cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - 127.0.0.1:9500 $(java -jar cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - 127.0.0.1:9500 |grep "com.mchange.v2.c3p0" |sed -n 1p) minPoolSize 2>&1 |awk '{print $6}'
50

its a stderr...